# uncaught exception PDOException even though statement is in a try/catch block

Tags: php

I have run into an unexpected fatal error while testing an app that uses my database utility class (see code below).  Here is a rundown of the test that was performed:

1. a new product was added to the database
2. the new product was put on an order
3. an attempt was made to delete the new product (while it was still being used on an order)

Results:

- as expected, the foreign key constraint in the database prevented deletion of the product
- unexpectedly, the following fatal error was displayed -
   `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Orders_Products". The conflict occurred in database "AppTEST", table "dbo.Orders", column 'productID'.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\App\classes\utility\DB.php:140 Stack trace: ...`
  Line 140 is `$stmt->execute();`, which is in the `query()` method in the code below.
  Forum posts describing similar errors called out prepending global classes with a backslash, which I did, but to no avail.  Why is the fatal error occurring?

Here are the pertinent parts of my database utility class for this question:

```
namespace classes\utility;

use \PDO,
    \Exception,
    \PDOException;

class DB
{
    private $_pdo,          # stores PDO object when it's instantiated
            $_error,        # stores whether query failed or not
            $_results,      # stores dataset returned by query
            $_count = 0;    # stores number of data rows returned

    /*connect to database*/
    private function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $connection = new \PDO('sqlsrv:Server=' . DB_HOST . ';Database=' . DB_NAME);
            $connection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     //to capture error messages returned by db
            $this->setPdo($connection);
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e)
        {
            exit((DEBUGMODE) ? $e->getMessage() : 'There was a problem connecting to the database.');
        }
    }

    # generic query method - uses named placeholders for parameter binding
    private function query($sql, $parameters = [])
    {
        try
        {
            $this->setError(false);
            $stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql); //assign to a variable with a short name
            if ($stmt):             
                if (count($parameters)):
                    foreach($parameters as $name => $parameter):
                        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$name, $parameter);                        
                    endforeach;
                endif;              
                $stmt->execute();
                $this->setCount($stmt->rowCount());
                if ($stmt->rowCount() == -1):       //conditionally do the following if SQL stmt was a SELECT
                    $this->setResults($stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
                    $this->setCount($stmt->rowCount()); //overwrite count attribute with number of rows returned by SELECT stmt
                endif;
            endif;
            return $this;
        }
        catch (\PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->setError(true);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    // setter and getter methods for private variables not shown

}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the code that calls the `query()` method.  This method is also part of the `DB` class.

```
public function runQuery($operation, $sql, $parameters)
{       
    try
    {
        $this->query($sql, $parameters);                        //call query method all $operation types (read, write)
        if ($operation == 'read'):          
            if ($this->getCount()):
                if ($this->getCount() > 1):                     //for "read all"
                    $data = $this->getResults();
                else:                                           //for "read one"
                    $data = $this->getFirstResult();
                endif;
                $data = Arr::objectToArray($data);
                return $data;
            else:
                throw new \Exception("No data to display.");        //throw an exception if query runs fine but returns zero rows
            endif;
        endif;
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e)
    {
        throw (DEBUGMODE) ? $e : new \Exception("A database error occurred.  The $operation operation failed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you *call* your `query()` method?  *That* would need to be in a try/catch.

Comment: `query()` is called by a method that is also wrapped in a try/catch block.

Comment: Can you show that code to complete the example?  The error is saying that you’re not catching the exception, so you should focus on the code that’s catching and handling the exception.

Comment: Yes, I will add it to the original post.

Comment: Ok, and where do you call *this* method and catch *its* exception?  A pattern seems to be emerging here.  The error is saying that an exception isn’t being caught, and your code is explicitly throwing exceptions from catch blocks.  It seems somewhere you have a top-level method call that isn’t being caught.

Comment: In `runQuery` if `DEBUGMODE` is true (or not set, which case it will be interpreted as the string `'DEBUGMODE'` which evaluates to true in a boolean context), you are throwing the exception again. Where does that get caught?

Comment: I have followed the chain of calls and all of them have a try/catch block.  What doesn't make sense to me is the fatal error specifically calls out line 140 and that is within the try block.

Comment: `DEBUGMODE` is a constant defined in a config file.  The same fatal error message occurs whether that constant is set to 1 or 0.

Comment: @knot22: That’s the location of the original exception that you keep re-throwing and don’t catch somewhere.

Comment: @David - Oh, so I need to keep looking for calls further up the chain?  I thought I checked them all, but I will look again.

Comment: All callers are wrapped in try/catch blocks.

Comment: As an experiment, I commented out the try/catch blocks in all methods that lead up to the `query()` method (but left the try/catch block in the `query` method).  The same fatal error message is occurring under these conditions.  Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be missing a backslash in a calling method.  I had prepended the backslash in all references to global classes in the DB class, but not in other classes in other namespaces that had catch blocks.

There were actually 2 different ways to resolve this problem.
One approach was to change `catch (Exception $e)` to `catch (\Exception $e)`.  
Alternatively, leaving `catch (Exception $e)` as-is throughout the code and adding `use \Exception;` after the namespace declaration and before the class definition worked as well.